# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method error in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I got this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

What I am trying to do is to list all of my values in my database.

Here is the code in my view:

```
  <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("SelectedScheduleId", Model.ScheduleSelectListItems, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sched_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
  </div>
```

Here is my class in my model:

```
  public class BookingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Description too short. Must be at least {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 10)]
        [Display(Name = "Describe your Consultation")]
        public string appointment_description { get; set; }
        public int appointment_id { get; set; }
        public int student_id { get; set; }
        public int sched_id { get; set; }
        public sched sched { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ScheduleSelectListItems { get; set; }
        public int SelectedScheduleId { get; set; }
    }
```

and my controller:

```
public ActionResult Book()
{
    var items = db.scheds.Select(sched => new SelectListItem { Text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", sched.sched_stime, sched.sched_etime), Value = sched.sched_id.ToString() });

    var model = new BookingModel { ScheduleSelectListItems = items };
    return View(model);
}
```

I just want to place the values of my sched table into a dropdown list.

I have consulted someone about how to list values of the foreign key and now I've ended up with a new error. How can I fix this? This is the only thing standing between me and finishing my project. :(

Comment: Materialize you query first - `db.scheds.ToList().Select(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's clear you can't use `string.Format` when you working with **LinqToSQL**.

You have 2 options:

```
var items = db.scheds
   .ToList()
   .Select(sched => new SelectListItem 
   { 
      Text = string.Format("{0} - {1}", sched.sched_stime, sched.sched_etime),    
      Value = sched.sched_id.ToString() 
   });
```

Use `.ToList()` to populate your table from db to server. Then you will work with **LinQToObjects** when you call `string.Format`.

Or concatenate your string without `string.Format`:

```
Text = sched.sched_stime + " - " + sched.sched_etime,
```

Then **LinQToSQL** be able to translate it.

Comment: `I suppose it's clear...` - apparently not, otherwise the question wouldn't be asked :-)

Comment: @Maarten You right, that's why i explain it in details ;)

Comment: Also, don't confuse **LinqToSql** with **Entity Framework**, they are not the same.

Comment: wow thank you so much! sorry I couldn't understand the solutions that was already been given. I am having a hard time how can I implement those to my code. I would study on how the result happened. Thank you again sir!

Comment: I noticed that the sched_id was returned as a string. can i possibly return back as an int? @teovankot

Comment: @MichaelZ no you have to option becouse you use `SelectListItem` and actually you don't need it - everything is string in html.